# Core Data on background thread not saving/persisting

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data

I am having an issue where objects that are saved to Core Data on a background thread are not persisting in the sqlite database.

On each backgroundFetch event my app reads activity recognition data from the CMMotionActivityManager and saves the activities into Core Data. This process is fully working when it happens while the app is in the foreground.

I am using the Unit Of Work design pattern inspired by https://christiantietze.de/posts/2015/10/unit-of-work-core-data-transaction/ to handle separate ManagedObjectContexts, and perform sql-like transactions. I have registered for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` so that changes on other contexts are merged to the main one.

I have a class `CoreDataTransaction.swift` that sets up and executes Core Data code - it also contains the mergeContexts function:

```
init(backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext, mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext){
    self.managedObjectContext = backgroundContext
    self.parentManagedObjectContext = mainContext
    super.init()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "mergeContexts:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: self.managedObjectContext)
}

func execute(closure: (context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Void){

  managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait { () -> Void in

    do {
      try closure(context: self.managedObjectContext)
    }catch let error as NSError{
      self.errorHandler?(error)
      return
    }

    do {
      print("saving managedObjectContext")
      try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    }catch let error as NSError{
      self.errorHandler?(error)
      return
    }

    self.parentManagedObjectContext.performBlock({
      do {
        print("saving parentManagedObjectContext")
        try self.parentManagedObjectContext.save()
      } catch let error as NSError{
        self.errorHandler?(error)
        return
      }

    })

  }

}

func mergeContexts(notification: NSNotification) {
  let savedContext = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext

  if(!NSThread.isMainThread()){
    self.performSelectorOnMainThread("mergeContexts:", withObject: notification, waitUntilDone: true)
    return
  }

  if(parentManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator == savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator){
    print("parentManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator == savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator")
    return
  }

  if(savedContext == self.managedObjectContext){

    parentManagedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait { () -> Void in
      print("merging changes")
      self.parentManagedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea where I could be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean background thread as in a non-main thread executing while the app is in the foreground? cos it sounds a little like you mean just that the app is in the background, which is something entirely different.

Comment: I mean that this is executing while the app is in the background, during the background fetch event. I didn't realise that was different, does that change anything?

Comment: I should probably add that the backgroundContext is .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType and the mainContext is .MainQueueConcurrencyType

Comment: Yes, very different. Your app will become suspended in the background, which means it will stop running. You can request extra execution time. Check the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1